# Android listview with header: list seems to always request focus

Tags: android

I have a listview where I add a headerview in which some stuff can be edited using textedits with a popup for suggestions (AutoCompleteTextView).
The main issue is that the popup always closes almost immedeatly (time varys from almost instantly to mabe 1 second).

I've looked at the call trace whenever the popup is dismissed and it turns out that Android internally does some layout adjustments and due to those the list is always requesting focus!

See stack trace here, I've censored a bit as it is not my own code on which I'm working! It is just the class name which is extending list view.
Imgur link because I have not enough rep.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJDZv.jpg

Request focus is not called by the user. It is internal stuff calling it..

What I've tried: (1) setFocusable(false) on the list view - didn't do anything, I could also still click on the list view so I'm not sure if that is supposed to be possible.. yet the listview still requested focus successfully..
(2) Manually call requestFocus for the search control if it's focus changed. - This resulted in the popup being visible but it was not possible to type into the text edit anymore..

I'm kind of out of ideas of what I'm supposed to do to get this fixed..
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Issue was actually caused by an event system in the app causing both views of the activity to ping-pong their focus...